# Do I need a reverse proxy (Nginx) in front of my Dash app?

Tags: nginx, flask, digital-ocean, plotly-dash

I’m developing a Dash app that makes requests to two Flask-RESTful apps to get data and populate different tables and graphs. I’m planning to deploy these apps on a DigitalOcean droplet where they will be put in Docker containers. I read that the Flask built-in server has some limitations and that it’s suitable for development purposes mainly. My user base is not large (10 people at most) but I wonder if I would run into some problems when my app needs to handle multiple requests. Do I need to use a reverse proxy such as Nginx in front of my Dash app and why?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Flask is only used for developing because of

- security reasons
- Flask is not able to handle parallelism (so all requests get processed sequentially)

Even if you user base isn't large I would suggest using an other WSGI HTTP server. A good choice for you could be [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org). It's written in python and using it with Flask or Dash is very simple.

If your Flask app name in your python file is `app` and you file is name `dash_app.py` it is as simple as using

```
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:7000 -w 4 dash_app:app
```

to launch your app listening on your primary interface on port 7000 with 4 workers.

If you just have no Flask server variable but only the Dash variable in you dash_app.py it would be as simple as

```
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:7000 -w 4 dash_app:app.server
```

See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04 for detailed Information.